# Cloudinary api - resolve promise

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I want to write a function that returns a Boolean indicating whether an image with the specified public_id already exists in my Cloudinary space.

I can log the result to the console with the following code:

```
function isUploaded(public_id) {
  cloudinary.api.resource(public_id, function(response){
    console.log(response.hasOwnProperty('public_id'));
  });
};

isUploaded('test');
```

However, I want to pass on the result, the Boolean, to another function. Using a return statement results in `{ state: 'pending' }` being logged:

```
function isUploaded(public_id) {
  return cloudinary.api.resource(public_id, function(response){
    return response.hasOwnProperty('public_id');
  });
};

console.log(isUploaded('test'));
```

This is has something to do with javascript Promises. I can't seem to restructure my code to make it work though. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `cloudinary.api.resource` runs asynchronously (which is why it requires a callback function).

You can make your `isUploaded` function return a `Promise` that resolves once that callback is called.

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

function isUploaded(public_id) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    cloudinary.api.resource(public_id, function(response) {
      var isUploaded = response.hasOwnProperty('public_id');
      resolve(isUploaded);
    });
  });
};

isUploaded('test')
.then(function (result) {
  console.log(result);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `api.resource()` is rate limited (part of the [Admin API](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api)) so this is not a "scalable" solution.

You can perform a HEAD request and get the `statusCode` of the response - 200 means the resource exists in your account, 404 otherwise.

For example -

```
var http = require('http')
var options = {method: 'HEAD', host:'res.cloudinary.com',path:'/<cloud_name>/image/upload/<yourimage.jpg>'} 
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {console.log(res.statusCode);});  
req.end();
```