# Problem uploading multiple images in node.js/Mongodb with Multer and Cloudinary

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multer, cloudinary

I'm having an issue trying to upload multiple images to my page. I'm using Multer and Cloudinary. Since Cloudinary doesn't have a method for multiple uploads, I passed the array of images (previously extracted with Multer) through a forEach. Ok, the images are successfully uploaded to mi cloudinary container. The problem comes into the upload function, when I trie to push the secure url and the public id into req.body.product. If I console.log(req.body.product) outside the upload function, it returns name and price (data from the form) but nothing about the arrays of images an ids. But if I console.log it inside de upload function, it returns the complet object (name, price, and both arrays). Product.create is taking the object without the arrays so I get my images uploaded to Cloudinary but I can't push the urls into my database to use in the showpage. It seems to me there's a scope issue I'm overlooking, but I can't figure out. Multer and cloudinary are correctly configured, I'm being able to upload single images in another routes.

Thanks in advance

```
// CREATE PRODUCT
router.post('/categorias/:categorie', middleware.adminCheck, upload.array('images'), function (req, res) {
    Categorie.findOne({url: req.params.categorie}, function (err, categorie) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            req.body.product.images = [];
            req.body.product.ids    = [];
            req.files.forEach(function (file) {
                cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.path, function (result) {
                    req.body.product.images.push(result.secure_url);
                    req.body.product.ids.push(result.public_id);
                    console.log(req.body.product);
                });
            });
            console.log(req.body.product);
            Product.create(req.body.product, function (err, product) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    categorie.products.push(product);
                    categorie.save();
                    res.redirect('/categorias/' + categorie.url);
                }
            });     
        }
    });
});
```

[-----UPDATE-----]

I fixed the timing issue using promises and even setTimeout but I find the problem remains. At least in both cases if I console.log(req.body.product)before Product.create I get the complete object like this:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  name: '12',
  price: '12',
  images:
   [ 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dm3wxeaiz/image/upload/v1602339704/xjknwth8mscexukjaznv.jpg',
     'https://res.cloudinary.com/dm3wxeaiz/image/upload/v1602339704/pddcxhvxfcc2zjfjjk3c.jpg' ],
  ids: [ 'xjknwth8mscexukjaznv', 'pddcxhvxfcc2zjfjjk3c' ] }
```

But if a console.log the product anywhere inside Product.create I get this:

```
{ _id: 5f81c37fbf3da50fb6ba3e1c, name: '12', price: 12, __v: 0 }
```

which finally gets stored in my db.
Will it have to do with the[Object: null prototype] that I'm getting before Product.create?  It seems like theres no way to pass the complete object through Product.create, for some reason. Could it be a problem with body parser?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary uploader is asynchronous and it might not have finished executing when you are printing the console.log outside the scope of the uploader but it eventually executes and returns the result inside the uploader. Here is an example of implementing it using a Promise and then() call: [Cloudinary api - resolve promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701013/cloudinary-api-resolve-promise)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you might rearrange the code so that the Cloudinary response data is available to the Product.create function:

```
router.post(
  '/categorias/:categorie',
  middleware.adminCheck,
  upload.array('images'),
  function(req, res) {
    Categorie.findOne({ url: req.params.categorie }, function(err, categorie) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        req.body.product.images = []
        req.body.product.ids = []
        req.files.forEach(function(file) {
          cloudinary.uploader
            .upload(file.path)
            .then(result => {
              req.body.product.images.push(result.secure_url)
              req.body.product.ids.push(result.public_id)
              console.log(req.body.product)
              Product.create(req.body.product, function(err, product) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err)
                } else {
                  categorie.products.push(product)
                  categorie.save()
                  res.redirect('/categorias/' + categorie.url)
                }
              })
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
            })
        })
      }
    })
  }
)
```